# Compute the probability that the provided classifier label is correct

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, svm

A binary SVM classifier provides a label $y_c^{(i)}$ for each $i$-th sample provided. This is not assured to be corresponding to its true label $y^{(i)}$, since the classifier could have computed a boundary which misclassifies some samples.

Let's assume that somehow, in case of linear kernel for instance, I am able to find the distance $d$ between the $i$-th sample and the boundary, as shown in the figure.

[image]

This distance somehow tells me how confident is the classifier in stating that the $i$-th sample belongs to the selected class (either positive or negative).

**My problem**

When a class $C$ is provided (i.e., either $C='Y'$ or $C='N'$ for binary classification), how to compute the following probability?

$Pr(y^{(i)} = C\quad |\quad y_c^{(i)})$

That is: the probability that $C$ is the true label of the $i$-th sample, given that the classifier gave the opinion $y_c^{(i)}$ on the sample.

**My solution (and why it does not work)**

I tried to generalize by using the **true positive rate** of the classifier, that is:

$Pr(y^{(i)} = C\quad |\quad y_c^{(i)}) = \frac{n_{C,y_c^{(i)}}}{\sum_{C'}n_{C',y_c^{(i)}}}$

where $n_{C,y_c^{(i)}}$ is the number of samples of class $C$ that the classifier classified as $y_c^{(i)}$. However, this measure stays as it is for every sample in the set.

**What I would like to have**

I would like, instead, a measure that depends on the degree of confidence of the classifier, or, somehow, on the distance $d$ computed on the boundary.

Could you please provide some suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason the learning algorithm must be an SVM and not one which naturally outputs probabilities ? You might also want to look at this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76693/machine-learning-to-predict-class-probabilities

Comment: Unfortunately, I am constrained on the type of classifier.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SVMs do produce a decision function but it does not directly correspond to probability.  There is a way in LibSVM (and sklearn which uses that under the hood) to get probabilities using [Platt scaling](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639) which sounds like what you're looking for.  Some more details about how that works are here:

[How does sklearn.svm.svc's function predict_proba() work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally)

[Converting LinearSVC's decision function to probabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478000/converting-linearsvcs-decision-function-to-probabilities-scikit-learn-python)

Answer (score 2):

What you want sounds akin to a precision-recall (PR) curve. PR curves show precision (TP / (TP + FP)) as a function of recall (TP / (TP + FN)). Every PR point corresponds to a threshold $T$ on the SVM's output $d$ (signed distance to the hyperplane), that is positive if $d \geq T$ and negative otherwise.

As such, you could create a figure depicting precision as a function of decision threshold. The general shape of this figure will be similar to a PR curve, except that it will be stretched horizontally (because not every unique decision value corresponds to a unique recall, the PR curve is more dense horizontally).

It must be noted that, perhaps contrary to intuition, precision is not necessarily highest for the largest decision values ($d$).